# How to prevent static method from creating a null object

Tags: c#, oop, methods, constructor

I have a static method that I call that checks if an object should be added and if calls the constructor if it should add it.  Then if not it should really do nothing.  I thought returning null would achieve this but it is creating an object with none of the properties being populated.  This is then causing a runtime eror later.

This is my code:

```
public static WorkSheets AddSheet(string dataPath, string exportFile, string finalFile, string tabName)
{
    if (File.Exists(dataPath + exportFile))
    {
        if (!tabName.Contains("Forecast") & !tabName.Contains("Sales"))
            if (Functions.FileIsGood(dataPath + exportFile)) File.Copy(dataPath + exportFile, dataPath + finalFile, true);

        return new WorkSheets(dataPath, exportFile, finalFile, tabName);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and my constructor:

```
public WorkSheets(string dataPath, string exportFile, string finalFile, string tabName)
{
     this.ExportFile = dataPath + exportFile;
     this.Path = dataPath + finalFile;
     this.TabName = tabName;
     this.DateError = !Functions.IsTodaysDate(ExportFile);
     this.WorksheetDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(ExportFile);
     this.SizeError = !Functions.IsCorrectSize(ExportFile);
     this.WorksheetSize = new FileInfo(ExportFile).Length;

}
```

Then I call the method like this:

```
worksheets.Add(WorkSheets.AddSheet(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath, Constants.PipeExport, Constants.PipeFinalFile, "Pipe"));
```

The issue I am having is with the return null; what can I do so it doesn't add the null object.

Comment: If the file exists, return the existing file, not null.

Comment: @csm_dev but if it doesn't exist, I want it to return nothing - no object, and that is the problem I am having.

Comment: I think you want logical and `&&`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, the problem I have is with the return null. the rest works correctly

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Probably the problem is in the code that uses this static method. The logic here seems to be correct. If the file doesn't exist do nothing and return null.

Comment: @Cowthulhu worksheets.Add(WorkSheets.AddSheet(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath, Constants.PipeExport, Constants.PipeFinalFile, "Pipe"));

Comment: You seem to be saying that the line `return null` is creating an object. It is certainly doing no such thing.

Comment: Split that line in two and check for null. Don't add if it is null

Comment: @Steve I put that code in the method because I was doing it numerous times and wanted to reduce the repeated code

Comment: Yes, but if you don't want a null added then you need to check for it. What is _worksheets_? Is this a `List<Worksheet>`?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get the return value from *AddSheet* in a temporary variable and check if it is null.
If it is null just don't add it to your list of worksheets

```
WorkSheets sheet = WorkSheets.AddSheet(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath, 
                       Constants.PipeExport, 
                       Constants.PipeFinalFile, 
                       "Pipe")); 
if(sheet != null) 
    worksheets.Add(sheet);
```

If you prefer to avoid repeating this check every time you add an element to the list then you can create a new class derived from `List<T>` and write your own  Add method that performs the check for null and add to the underlying base class if the element to add is not null.

```
public class ListWorkSheets : List<WorkSheets>
{
    public new void Add(WorkSheets source)
    {
        if(source != null)
            base.Add(source);
    }
}
```

Now you can declare

```
ListWorkSheets worksheets = new ListWorkSheets();
```

and use your current syntax without adding a null to your list

```
worksheets.Add(WorkSheets.AddSheet(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath, 
                                   Constants.PipeExport, 
                                   Constants.PipeFinalFile, 
                                   "Pipe"));
```

Comment: Steve your answer seems to be the best possible but when I declare it like you suggest it says 'Cannot implicitly convert type .... to ..... An Explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?")

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason but I have mispelled WorkSheets in WorkSheet. Now I have fixed the code to be compatible with the declared return type of AddSheet

Comment: No because I did that correctly. For now I did the longer fix of doing a check before I call the add method until I work on that another day.

Comment: Oh, well it should work at least on my tests. But can you add the missing parts in your first comment? I mean the text in place of the dots from the compiler error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try some conditional logic before adding the instance to the list.

IE

```
Worksheet tempWorkSheet = WorkSheets.AddSheet(CurrentWorkbook.DataPath, Constants.PipeExport, Constants.PipeFinalFile, "Pipe");

if (tempWorkSheet != null)
{
    worksheets.Add(TempWorkSheet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your method has a declared return type you have to return that type or null.

You could throw an exception instead.

Or you change the return type to void and declare an out parameter for your result

Alternatively you could save the result of your call that instantiates the object and check for null.

```
var tmp =  WorkSheets.AddSheet(foo);
if(tmp != null) {
  worksheets.Add(tmp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend one of the following:

1. What @Steve said: split up your function call and check for null in the return.
2. Wrap your function call in a try/catch block then have your function return an exception if it can't find the file.

If it's a rare anomaly where a file can't be found then the exception is likely the 'correct' way to go from a methodology standpoint.  If it's common for incorrect paths to be attempted, then returning null and having a check like Steve said is probably best.  It's more a question of code methodology than technical requirement at that point.